# Convert 2D coordinates to 3D, knowing the starting and finishing 3D coordinates - Python

Tags: python, 3d, 2d, coordinates

I want to approximate the 3D path for a ball extracting some of its positions from video. I'm able to locate the centroid for the ball in each frame it appears on its path from the release point to the landing zone. This is an example of that:

[image: Ball on its path]

I have the exact starting point in 3D coordinates (x1,y1,z1) and also have the exact landing point in 3D coordinates (x2, y2, z2). Through object detection techniques with OpenCV, I was able to extract discrete 2D positions ("a0, b0" - "a1, b1" ... "an, bn") for the ball during its travel from starting point to the landing point and my intention is to do some sort of reconstruction for the ball's traveling path but in 3D coordinates, using the 3D starting and landing coordinates as some sort of reference frame.

I'm pretty sure this is doable and would love to know about other efforts around it as I don't want to reinvent the wheel :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a spitballing:) First, we can calculate a straight line in 3d between starting and landing points. Then, somehow we calculate a 3D trajectory points on the basis of this triangle made of starting point, landing point, and 2D coordinates.

Comment: That's basically my thinking too, in a nutshell. I was just looking if there was an already-tested framework for it out there :) Thanks!